# Tuples and Ternary and positional parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given:

```
>>> a,b=2,3
>>> c,d=3,2
>>> def f(x,y): print(x,y)
```

I have an existing (as in cannot be changed) 2 positional parameter function where I want the positional parameters to always be in ascending order; i.e., `f(2,3)` no matter what two arguments I use (`f(a,b)` is the same as `f(c,d)` in the example)

I know that I could do:

```
>>> f(*sorted([c,d]))
2 3
```

Or I could do:

```
>>> f(*((a,b) if a<b else (b,a)))
2 3
```

([Note](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-January/519738.html) the need for tuple parenthesis in this form because `,` is lower precedence than the ternary...)

Or,

```
def my_f(a,b):
    return f(a,b) if a<b else f(b,a)
```

All these seem kinda kludgy. Is there another syntax that I am missing?

---

*Edit*

I missed an 'old school' Python two member tuple method. Index a two member tuple based on the True == 1, False == 0 method:

```
>>> f(*((a,b),(b,a))[a>b])
2 3
```

Also:

```
>>> f(*{True:(a,b), False:(b,a)}[a<b])
2 3
```

---

*Edit 2*

The reason for this silly exercise: [numpy.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) has the following usage note:

> For finite values, isclose uses the following equation to test whether
>   two floating point values are equivalent.
>
> absolute(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * absolute(b))
>
> The above equation is not symmetric in a and b, so that isclose(a, b)
>   might be different from isclose(b, a) in some rare cases.

I would prefer that not happen.

I am looking for the fastest way to make sure that arguments to `numpy.isclose` are in a consistent order. That is why I am shying away from `f(*sorted([c,d]))`

Comment: The first one doesn't seem too kludgy, otherwise I guess you could just sort inside the function instead?

Comment: I agree with @A.J., the first one is clean enough.

Comment: You could write a decorator function that sorts the arguments before passing them to the function `@sorted def f(x, y): print(x, y)`

Comment: @KeiferSebastian well since the function cannot be changed I assume the OP couldn't just use it as a decorator, but yes doing `my_f = sorted(original_f)` would still be an option. (probably use a name like `sort_args` though)

Comment: The 'old school' idiom is also the least recognized. Is there any reason why you don't like the `sorted` option? Do you think it it "too much"?

Comment: It's strange that you're trying to make order of arguments user-code responsibility. Why not sorting them inside of your function instead?

Comment: @user1685095: It is a library function [numpy.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) where `isclose(a,b)` *may* return a result different than `isclose(b,a)`

Comment: Well, then `isclose = sorted(isclose)` should work.

Comment: I'd say the most readable (i.e. concise while making the intention of the code clear) is `f(*sorted([a,b]))`. After that, probably `f(a,b) if a<b else f(b,a)`.

Comment: @user1685095: no, that is the wrong thing to sort. It would be `isclose(*sorted(a,b))`

Comment: @dawg I meant the `sort` decorator presented in answer of course. Not the sort function.

Answer (score 6):

Implemented my solution in case anyone else is looking.

```
def sort(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        return f(*sorted(args))
    return wrapper

@sort
def f(x, y):
    print(x, y)

f(3, 2)

>>> (2, 3)
```

Also since @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen mention that you may not be able to change the function yourself that you could wrap the function as such

```
my_func = sort(f)
```

Comment: Or using decorator like that! See my comment on question.

Comment: The advantage of this decorator approach is that the working mechanism of `wrapper` can easily change.

Answer (score 5):

You mention that your use-case is `np.isclose`. However your approach isn't a good way to solve the **real** issue. But it's understandable given the poor argument naming of that function - it sort of implies that both arguments are interchangable. If it were: `numpy.isclose(measured, expected, ...)` (or something like it) it would be much clearer.

For example if you expect the value `10` and measure `10.51` and you allow for 5% deviation, then in order to get a useful result you **must** use `np.isclose(10.51, 10, ...)`, otherwise you would get **wrong** results:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> measured = 10.51
>>> expected = 10
>>> err_rel = 0.05
>>> err_abs = 0.0

>>> np.isclose(measured, expected, err_rel, err_abs)
False
>>> np.isclose(expected, measured, err_rel, err_abs)
True
```

It's clear to see that the first one gives the correct result because the **actually measured value** is *not* within the tolerance of the **expected** value. That's because the relative uncertainty is an "attribute" of the expected value, not of the value you compare it with!

So solving this issue by "sorting" the parameters is just wrong. That's a bit like changing the numerator and denominator for division because the denominator contains zeros and dividing by zero could give `NaN`, `Inf`, a Warning or an Exception... it definetly avoids the problem but just by giving an incorrect result (the comparison isn't perfect because with division it will almost always give a wrong result; with `isclose` it's rare).

This was a somewhat artificial example designed to trigger that behaviour and most of the time it's not important if you use `measured, expected` or `expected, measured` but in the few cases where it does matter you can't solve it by swapping the arguments (except when you have no "expected" result, but that rarely happens - at least it shouldn't).

There was some discussion about this topic when `math.isclose` was added to the python library:

> #### [Symmetry (PEP 485)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0485/#symmetry)
>
> [...]
>
> Which approach is most appropriate depends on what question is being asked. If the question is: "are these two numbers close to each other?", there is no obvious ordering, and a symmetric test is most appropriate.
>
> However, if the question is: "Is the computed value within x% of this known value?", then it is appropriate to scale the tolerance to the known value, and an asymmetric test is most appropriate.
>
> [...]
>
> This proposal [for `math.isclose`] uses a symmetric test.

So if your test falls into the first category and you like a symmetric test - then [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.isclose) could be a viable alternative (at least if you're dealing with scalars):

> #### [math.isclose(a, b, *, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0)](https://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.isclose)
>
> [...]
>
> *rel_tol* is the relative tolerance – it is the maximum allowed difference between *a* and *b*, relative to the **larger absolute value of *a* or *b***. For example, to set a tolerance of 5%, pass `rel_tol=0.05`. The default tolerance is `1e-09`, which assures that the two values are the same within about 9 decimal digits. *rel_tol* must be greater than zero.
>
> [...]

---

Just in case this answer couldn't convince you and you still want to use a `sorted` approach - then you should order by the `abs`olute of you values (i.e. `*sorted([a, b], key=abs)`). Otherwise you might get surprising results when comparing negative numbers:

```
>>> np.isclose(-10.51, -10, err_rel, err_abs)   # -10.51 is smaller than -10!
False
>>> np.isclose(-10, -10.51, err_rel, err_abs)
True
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For only two elements in the tuple, the second one is the preferred idiom -- in my experience.  It's fast, readable, etc.

No, there isn't really another syntax.  There's also

```
(min(a,b), max(a,b))
```

... but this isn't particularly superior to the other methods; merely another way of expressing it.

**Note after comment by `dawg`**:

A class with custom comparison operators could return the same object for both `min` and `max`.

Comment: The problem here is if `a==b` and they are otherwise separate objects...